# Prove derivative rule using analogous polynomial formula

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$$x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)
x^n - a^n = (x-a) (x^n-1  + ax^n-2  +\dotsb+  a^n-1),$$

so using the latter factorization formula, prove:

$$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}  = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x-a}.$$

I was able to plug in my derived formula in line two and cancel out denominator.  Not sure how to approach the rest to show it is $f'(a)$.  Sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f'(a)
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{(x-a)(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+\cdots+a^{n-1})}{x-a} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} (x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+\cdots+a^{n-1}) \\
&=& \displaystyle (\underbrace{a^{n-1}+aa^{n-2}+\cdots+a^{n-1}}_{n\text{ terms}}) \\
&=& na^{n-1} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: what happened at the 4th line?

Comment: @AliRaza We substituted $x \to a$

Comment: how did the n term come out in front?  I understand the a^n-1 term

Comment: @AliRaza because there are $n$ terms in $x^{n-1} + ax^{n-2} + \cdots + a^{n-1}$

Comment: wow ok I see it now.  Thank you!